# Polymorphic overloading - how to force an abstract type to "act" as one of its derived types for the purposes of overloaded parameters?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overloading

```
DoSomething(Car car);
DoSomething(Bike bike);

public class Car : Vehicle {}
public class Bike : Vehicle {}
public abstract class Vehicle {}


void run(Vehicle vehicle) {
    DoSomething(vehicle);
}
```

This feels like a simple problem but I'm having issues.  DoSomething(Vehicle vehicle) doesn't exist, so DoSomething(vehicle) throws an error, even though vehicle is "guaranteed" to be either Car or Bike.  How can I convince the compiler that "vehicle" is Bike or Car, so that DoSomething can be run?

Of course I could just have another method along the lines of

```
DoSomething(Vehicle vehicle)
{
    if(vehicle is Car) ... etc
}
```

But surely there is a cleaner approach?

**EDIT/CLARITY**

The motivation for putting this code in a manager class, rather than having DoSomething() exist in the Vehicle class, is that each Vehicle needs to access different parts of the program.  For example:

```
DoSomething(Car car) {
    motorwayInfo.CheckMotorwayStatus();
}
DoSomething(Bike bike) {
    cycleInfo.CheckCyclePathStatus();
}
```

Not sure if this analogy is really getting across my particular issue that well, hah - but basically I don't want Car's to have any reference to cycleInfo, nor Bikes to have any reference to motorWayInfo.  But, putting DoSomething into Vehicle basically means its parameter needs to either be:

```
DoSomething(CycleInfo cycleInfo, MotorwayInfo motorwayInfo)
```

or

```
DoSomething(InfoManager infoManager)
```

Neither of which seem totally ideal, as I know that each subtype is only going to use a specific info object.  Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real question here is - what do you expect to happen *to the* method's parameter? If that, whatever it is, depends on a concrete (sub)type of the parameter, then the proper place for that behavior is in the virtual (or even abstract) member of the parameter base class - `Vehicle`.

```
class Vehicle
{
    public abstract void Behave();
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public override void Behave()
    {
        // Do something specific to a car
    }
}

class Bike : Vehicle
{
    public override void Behave()
    {
        // Do something specific to a bike
    }
}
...
void Run(Vehicle vehicle)
{
    vehicle.Behave();
}
```

As you can see from this code, I have reverted the roles. The `Run` function is *not* responsible to know how a concrete parameter should behave. Instead, each concrete object passed as the `Vehicle` parameter would have to know how to behave. That is the proper polymorphism.

Regarding the `Run` method, all its responsibilities regarding the argument should relate to the common type of all parameter objects, and that is the base class `Vehicle`. In that respect, the method could access members defined on the base class, or insert the object into a collection, etc.

```
void Run(Vehicle vehicle)
{
    vehicle.Behave();

    List<Vehicle> list = ...
    list.Add(vehicle);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is in fact  how the code was previously laid out, and perhaps that's the way it should be.  I'd switched them around in order to have Vehicle be as close to a strict data container as possible, because it felt like I was mixing together my logic and data a bit too much.  But you're right, it kind of undermines the purpose of polymorphism to then handle their functionality in a separate management class

Comment: @Cerzi The whole point of OOP is to put common data and logic together.

Comment: Check my edit - tried to clarify the slightly more complex setup i have and how it's making me feel like the usual approach to polymorphism isnt that clean.

Comment: Is this a case of choosing the lesser of two evils or is there a neat way I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Cerzi I've added an update to show that Zoran's answer is correct and will work for your more complex case.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called [Double Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) and is not supported natively by the C# compiler.

You can achieve it with some refactoring though:

```
public void DoSomething(Car car) {}
public void DoSomething(Bike bike) {}

public abstract class Vehicle
{
    // ...
    public abstract void CallDoSomething();
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public override void CallDoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(this);
    }
}

public class Bike : Vehicle
{
    public override void CallDoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(this);
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't care about the performance penalty, you can use the `dynamic` keyword that will defer the overload resolution until runtime then chooses the most appropriate method that matches the type:

```
void run(dynamic vehicle)
{
    DoSomething(vehicle);
}
```

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

Comment: Great answer. To achieve double dispatch you can also use the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> vehicle is "guaranteed" to be either Car or Bike

That's not true. If all Cars are Vehicles and all Bikes are Vehicles, that does not mean that all Vehicles are either Bikes or Cars. Subtyping does not work that way.

> How can I convince the compiler that "vehicle" is Bike or Car, so that DoSomething can be run?

The only way to do that is by casting, which you already mentioned:

```
if (vehicle is Car) (vehicle as Car).CheckMotorwayStatus();
else if (vehicle is Bike) (vehicle as Bike).CheckCyclePathStatus();
```

> But surely there is a cleaner approach?

The approach that Zoran's answer suggested is the cleaner approach.

> I don't want Car's to have any reference to cycleInfo, nor Bikes to have any reference to motorWayInfo.

With some thought, you can use it even with your slightly more complex setup. [For example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yd9foc):

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public abstract void PrintRouteStatus();
}

public class MotorwayInfo
{
}

public class CycleInfo
{
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    // probably pass this in via a constructor.
    public MotorwayInfo _motorwayInfo = new MotorwayInfo();
    public override void PrintRouteStatus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_motorwayInfo);
    }
}

public class Bike : Vehicle
{
    // probably pass this in via a constructor.
    public CycleInfo _cycleInfo = new CycleInfo();
    public override void PrintRouteStatus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_cycleInfo);
    }
}
```

It works without Car being aware at all of Bike's info and vice versa.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var p = new Program();
    p.DoSomething(new Car());
    p.DoSomething(new Bike());
}

public void DoSomething(Vehicle v)
{
    v.PrintRouteStatus();
}
```

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Before your edit it was just correcting an assumption the OP made.

Comment: I feel like this is just shifting the problem elsewhere though.  Like you say, the reference to (in this example) MotorwayInfo has to be passed in at some point, probably in the constructor.  But, when loading objects dynamically as my code is, this still means there needs to be an explicit test of type.  eg "if(VehicleToAdd() == typeof(Car)) new car(motowayinfo); else new bike(cycleinfo);"

Comment: @Cerzi Without know more about the data modeling problem that you're trying to solve, it is hard to give more specific advice. My sense is that Zoran gave a good answer to your original question. It might be worth asking a new question on StackOverflow that includes more of the design constraints. One possible solution is to have MotorwayInfo and CycleInfo both inherit from an abstract RouteInfo class. It isn't clear though whether that works with you're design constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised none of these answers included generics or interfacing. Instead of overriding subclass methods per instance, you can reverse this and create a single instance that accepts either.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {}
public class Car : Vehicle {}
public class Bike : Vehicle {}

public void DoSomething<T>(T _vehicle) where T : Vehicle
{
    // _vehicle can be an instance of Car or Bike

    if (_vehicle is Car _car)
        motorwayInfo.CheckMotorwayStatus();

    if (_vehicle is Bike _bike)
        cycleInfo.CheckCyclePathStatus();
}
```

You could take this a step further and implement an `IVehicle` interface.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I wrote what I coined as the "DoubleDispatchObject" to help solve this type of problem - notably,

1) without losing type safety (or resorting to the use of the dynamic keyword, be it at call sites or callees),

2) without burden on the choice of base classes (instead, the simple composition pattern is enough),

and 3) incurring only a couple lines of boilerplate.

here's what your scenario looks like, with it:

```
public class VehicleManager
{
  // boilerplate start
  private DoubleDispatchObject dispatch;

  public void DoSomething(Vehicle vehicle) =>
    this.EnsureThreadSafe(ref dispatch)
    .Via(nameof(DoSomething), vehicle, () => throw new NotImplementedException());
  // boilerplate end

  public void Run(Vehicle vehicle) =>
    DoSomething(vehicle);

  public void DoSomething(Car car) =>
    Console.WriteLine("Doing something with a car...");

  public void DoSomething(Bike bike) =>
    Console.WriteLine("Doing something with a bike...");
}

public abstract class Vehicle { }
public class Car : Vehicle { }
public class Bike : Vehicle { }

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var manager = new VehicleManager();
    manager.Run(new Car());
    manager.Run(new Bike());
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
  }
}
```

On repl.it :

https://repl.it/@ysharp_design/SO48975551

See also this related pull request (for the unit tests) :

https://github.com/waf/MultipleDispatchBenchmarks/pull/1/files

'HTH